# How do I get the pattern string from a pcre *?

Tags: c, pcre

I'm using the PCRE library in C.

After calling `pcre_compile()`, I get back a `pcre *`.

However, it doesn't seem like there are any library functions out there to get the pattern from a `pcre *` object.  The actual structure itself is meant to be private.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: That "pcre *" is a pointer to a compiled expression. You're not supposed to access it to "get the pattern"; you're supposed to use it in your subsequent operations, in order to avoid the expression having to be compiled again and again. What are you trying to do with the "pattern" after you get it?

Comment: Well it's not vitally important but I have a large array of pcre* and I wanted to display, for debugging reasons, what the pattern was when I was matching it

Comment: There's nothing to "display". It's a compiled expression. It would be like trying to display a C object file to show what code was executing in your app; there's no usable textual information there. It's a pointer to an in-memory structure that contains information; it's not meant to "view". You can keep track of which one by looking at the memory address of the pointer itself and matching to the array index.

Comment: Oh I get that it's a compiled data structure... I was just hoping there'd be some way, like pcre_fullinfo() (or something) to get back at the original pattern used to create the compiled expression.  I guess I'll have to maintain map myself to do it.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I just took a look through `pcre.h` and `internal.h`, and I don't see anything that might do so. I'd suspect your best bet would be just to keep a map between the original expressions and the index into your array.